# MySQL - How to constrain column A always mapping to the same value in column B

Tags: mysql

For this table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(id_code varchar(255), health_code varchar(255), exam_date date);
```

How to declare an efficient constraint to enforce column `health_code` always mapping to the same value in column `id_code`?

This is the expected behavior:

| id_code | health_code | exam_date | constraint result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 20220501 | init data |
| 2 | 22 | 20220501 | init data |
| 1 | 11 | 20220601 | good, your id_code and health code are consistent with row #1 |
| 2 | 33 | 20220601 | reject, you get a different health_code than row #2 |

Comment: above data in table is **insert** expected behavior?

Comment: Is the health code always related exactly to the id code (so that, for example, id_code 1 will always require health code 11), or is it the case the initial id code could have any health code, but subsequent references to that id code must have the same health code as the initial one?

Comment: Normalize your structure and move `(id_code, health_code)` to separate table defining each separate column in this table as UNIQUE (one of them may be primary key). Refer to this table from your current table. If not then only trigger logic may help - none constraint can check out of the row.

Comment: Why do you need two columns if there's a constant mapping between them?

Comment: @fver1004 yes, that's the expected

Comment: @Barmar It isn't constant mapping

Comment: You said "always mapping to the same value". Isn't that constant?

Comment: You can't use queries in constraints, so it can't check other rows of the table to see if the pairing is consistent with previous rows.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular good question, 1 isn't always mapped to 11, but subsequences follow the first(initial) mapping

Comment: @Akina I store this redundant data for business purpose, wide table, fast fetch. can you talk about the trigger logic concretely ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with a constraint, because constraints can't perform queries, which is how you would compare with other rows.

You can do it in a trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_codes BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM my_table 
    WHERE id_code = NEW.id_code AND health_code != NEW.health_code
    )
THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Inconsistent id_code and health_code'
END IF;
```

You can have a similar `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger in case someone tries to change one of the codes to an invalid value.

Comment: health_code always maps to same id_code but that doesn't necessarily mean id_code can only have 1 health_code.

Comment: OK, I removed the other half of the condition.

Comment: @P.Salmon That seems to be the opposite of his example.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, this is what I exactly mean to . 
I didn't use or know trigger before, just wonder the performance, especially when working with big volume. Say, when inserting 10k new rows with a million of existing rows, how about the performance ?

Comment: It will definitely slow things down, there's no free lunch. Make sure you index these columns.

Comment: sure thing, index certainly. gotcha, thx